# jQuery & Ajax - Load items to a select input when page loads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 `<select>` inputs:

```
<select id="state">
  <option value="" selected>Select</option>
  <option value="california">California</option>
  <option value="new-york">New York</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery/AJAX code:

```
$('#state').change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'state='+id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: scriptpath+'../ajax/fields.php',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(output) {
            $('#city').html(null);
            $('#city').append(output);
        },
    });
});
```

**Explanation:** Everything works fine. The `#city` input changes depending on the `#state` input value... Now if I load the page having `"california"` as the `default` value -- the `#city` input doesn't change since it's using the `.change()` event. How do I detect the selected value on the `#state` input when the page loads?

I've tried `$('#state').on("change load",function() {` without success.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a named function instead of the anonymous and call it on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger the change event when first page loads:

```
$('#state').change(function() {
    //your code...
}).change();//trigger on page load
```